# Send data from c# from to Arduino (Serial)

Tags: c#, c, winforms, serial-port, arduino-ide

I'd like to send data to my arduino from a windows form. The problem I'm having is that only one program can access the port at a time.

I created a program in the arduino to send out an analog video component signal on my tv. The windows form application will calculate positions for a space invader -alike game and send them to the serial.

Here's the c# form code to send the `array` of pixelpositions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ArduinoGame
{
    class SerialWriter
    {
        SerialPort sp;

        public SerialWriter()
        {
            sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM3";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        }
        public void CloseWriter()
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen) sp.Close();
        }

        public void WritePixelPos(Point[] pixels)
        {
            try
            {
                sp.Open(); 
                foreach (Point pixel in pixels)
                {
                    sp.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(pixel.X + "," + pixel.Y);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the arduino IDE, I'd like to catch every sentence from the serial, and use that data in a function, but I can't access it.

Basicly the form has to close the serial port when the arduino needs acces, and other way around.

Comment: *"Basicly the form has to close the serial port when the arduino needs acces, and other way around."* What does that mean? If you have 2 devices that are connected, they both need to be open to transfer bytes.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows only allows one process to access a serial port at any time. Is there a reason why you can't implement your function in the Windows Form app as this will be able to read from the serial port when it is connected?

Comment: I've added my own answer to it a few days ago, but I just noticed it didn't upload. The problem here was that I was openening the Serial Monitor on the Arduino IDE. From the moment I closed it, it was not a problem... such a little mistake always leads to a big mess for me :/